# Node.js port issue on Heroku cedar stack

Tags: node.js, heroku, port, express

I'm running a basic Express app in Node.js and trying to deploy to Heroku. The app works fine locally and I believe my setup with Heroku has gone well up until starting the server where i get the following error:

```
2011-09-21T16:42:36+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-09-21T16:42:39+00:00 app[web.1]: Express server listening on port 3000 in production mode
2011-09-21T16:42:40+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R11 (Bad bind) -> Process bound to port 3000, should be 12810 (see environment variable PORT)
2011-09-21T16:42:40+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2011-09-21T16:42:40+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
```

this is currently all i have in my app.js

```
app.listen(3000);
```

I did also run this as mentioned on Heroku's getting started.

```
$ heroku config:add NODE_ENV=production
Adding config vars:
NODE_ENV => production
```

I believe I just need to set up the port for production?  Thanks.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Can you show the entire section of code where you call `listen`? You should be checking for the process environment variable PORT, not just hardcoding it to 3000. From their [docs](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-js):

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, function() {
```

Comment: Cool, I updated the post. Do I need to switch to port 12810 for production somehow? Thanks

Comment: Ah, alright. Try calling listen using the logic I showed above, and see if it works.

Comment: this works, but what does `process.env.PORT` do?  Who sets it?

Comment: Heroku does: they inject the configuration variables when they start up a web dyno, and that is one of the variables they inject.

Comment: i can't find PORT variable in Environment variables, need to mention it in Procfile -p command. How can i do this?