# Node.js app in Heroku Works on Foreman but not When Deployed?

Tags: git, node.js, heroku, foreman

I successfully have my app running on foreman start perfectly well, but as soon as I deploy it to Heroku, it throws me an error in the logs:

```
2012-08-20T03:22:48+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2012-08-20T03:22:49+00:00 app[web.1]: Server has started.
2012-08-20T03:22:49+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R11 (Bad bind) -> Process bound to port 15134, should be 52717 (see environment variable PORT)
2012-08-20T03:22:49+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2012-08-20T03:22:51+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2012-08-20T03:22:51+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I have tried to change which port it binds to, but every time I do it changes the port again. Is there something else wrong in my app?

Comment: Are you trying to hardcode the port?  Heroku is going to want to bind to a different port every time.  Your Procfile should be using the `$PORT` variable, if it isn't already.

Comment: I should try that. Does Node.js support it?

Comment: Heroku will set the `PORT` environment variable, which is what you want to use.  This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503632/node-js-port-issue-on-heroku-cedar-stack

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work, just says "$PORT" is not defined

Comment: I am using Vanilla Node.js, no Express or any other framework

Comment: Check out the link.  node doesn't take the port as a command line argument (wouldn't make sense for node) but rather uses the PORT environment variable (`process.env.PORT` in node).  That's the port you have to bind to.  It's accessible via `$PORT` in the Procfile, but that's actually not useful to you in node (disregard the first comment).

Comment: Thanks! Works so well, the process.env.PORT! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

on Heroku, you need to use the port contained in an environment variable:
process.env.PORT