# Heroku won't load index.html

Tags: javascript, heroku

I'm trying to create a node.js application with Heroku. In my server.js file I use express to load a static html page. This is the express code in my server.js file. In the procfile from Heroku I set this as my starting point.

```
var app = require('express')();

var http = require('http').Server(app);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + 'index.html');
});
```

But when I push it to Heroku, Heroku doesn't show anything, so also no errors.

server.js, index.html are in the same folder

Comment: if you add `console.log(__dirname)` what you get in the console?

Comment: Console is empty

https://tap-to-race.herokuapp.com/

Comment: This is the output from "heroku logs"

http://pastebin.com/kMnewN1z

Comment: it returns `404` maybe your template engine dont accept `html`
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11495595/using-html-in-express-instead-of-jade

Comment: and BTW, why adding `require('http')` if you are using `express`, you already called the `http` module by calling `express`
here is a simple example
https://github.com/abdelouahabb/express-as-tornado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that your entire `server.js`? If so, you need to specify a port to be listened to:

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
server.listen(80);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
console.log('Express server started on port %s', server.address().port);
```

EDIT: As @Abdelouahab suggested, you shouldn't hardcode the port, rather grab it from process.env.PORT

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Node app is running at localhost:" + app.get('port'))
});
```

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#push-local-changes

[Node.js port issue on Heroku cedar stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503632/node-js-port-issue-on-heroku-cedar-stack)

Comment: in Heroku it is adviced to not hard code the port
`app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 80)`

`var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log('working! on port ' + app.get('port'))`
})