# I create a node app that is working locally. I need help to modify server.js so that it can work on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, express, socket.io, port

I create a node app that is working locally. I need help to modify server.js below so that it can work on heroku.

server.js:

```
var http = require('http');
var session = require('cookie-session');
var port = 9500; 
var Assets = require('./backend/Assets'); 
var API = require('./backend/API'); 

var Default = require('./backend/Default');
var Chat = require('./backend/Chat');  
var Router = require('./frontend/js/lib/router')();  

Router 
.add('static', Assets) 
.add('node_modules', Assets) 
.add('tests', Assets) 
.add('api', API) 
.add(Default);  

var checkSession = function(req, res) {
session({     
  keys: ['nodejs-by-example']
})(req, res, function() { 
  process(req, res);  
}); 
}  

var process = function(req, res) { 
  Router.check(req.url, [req, res]); 
}  

var app = http.createServer(checkSession).listen(port, '127.0.0.1'); 
console.log("Listening on 127.0.0.1:" + port);  
Chat(app);
```

I tried:

```
var port = Number(process.env.PORT || 9000);
```

But it didn't work. I got this error:

```
users-MacBook-Pro-6:project user$ node server
/Users/user/Desktop/project/server.js:3
var port = Number(process.env.PORT || 5000); 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'env' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Desktop/project/server.js:3:26)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are getting an undefined process variable.  To troubleshoot you should do a `console.dir(process)` which will print out everything on the process variable including your environment variables.

As well you can try doing this - `heroku config:set NODE_ENV=production` per [heroku support](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support)

Could possibly be [related to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503632/node-js-port-issue-on-heroku-cedar-stack).

**Update**

To further troubleshoot you will need to install a [logging addon](https://addons.heroku.com/papertrail)-

`heroku addons:create papertrail`

After you install you will be able to navigate to the add-on and see any messages that are being logged related to the deployment as well as your console.dir and console.log printouts.

Comment: I tried both console.dir(process) and  heroku config:set NODE_ENV=production but i have the same result